# What is a good way to replace hover effect in mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and it works fine in desktop view, but obviously hover effects don't work in the mobile view.

I would like to only show the images aligned vertically in the mobile view, but in a way so that the links still work. The text doesn't have to be shown.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
  }

  .image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%; /* Adjust width for desktop view */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .image-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .image-wrapper {
      width: 100%; 
    }
    .text-overlay {
      display: none; 
    }
  }

  .image-wrapper .text-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    line-height: 0.5;
  }

  .image-wrapper:hover .text-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .image-wrapper:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .text-overlay p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<div class="abstand"></div>

<!-- Row of images -->

<div class="image-container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="text-overlay">
      <p>Text to the image</p>
    </div>
    <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="image.png" alt="My image"/></a>
  </div>

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="text-overlay">
      <p>Text to the image</p>
    </div>
    <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="image.png" alt="My image"/></a>
  </div>

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="text-overlay">
      <p>Text to the image</p>
    </div>
    <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="image.png" alt="My image"/></a>
  </div>

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="text-overlay">
      <p>Text to the image</p>
    </div>
    <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="image.png" alt="My image"/></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Anyone an idea what's wrong, that is, why the links don't work and how I can fix this?

Comment: You should move your `:hover` style definition inside `media query` for larger screen size, so that smaller screen size does not have that hover effect.

Comment: That makes sense. It works now, thank you!